# Return value from ENUM

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, enums

I have a Java ENUM where I store different statuses:

```
public enum BusinessCustomersStatus {
    A("active", "Active"),
    O("onboarding", "Onboarding"),
    NV("not_verified", "Not Verified"),
    V("verified", "Verified"),
    S("suspended", "Suspended"),
    I("inactive", "Inactive");

    @Getter
    private String shortName;

    @JsonValue
    @Getter
    private String fullName;

    BusinessCustomersStatus(String shortName, String fullName) {
        this.shortName = shortName;
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    // Use the fromStatus method as @JsonCreator
    @JsonCreator
    public static BusinessCustomersStatus fromStatus(String statusText) {
        for (BusinessCustomersStatus status : values()) {
            if (status.getShortName().equalsIgnoreCase(statusText)) {
                return status;
            }
        }

        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(String.format("Unknown status: '%s'", statusText));
    }
}
```

Full code: https://github.com/rcbandit111/Search_specification_POC/blob/main/src/main/java/org/merchant/database/service/businesscustomers/BusinessCustomersStatus.java

The code works well when I want to get the list of items into pages for the value `fullName` because I use `@JsonValue` annotation.

I have a case where I need to get the `shortValue` for this code:

```
return businessCustomersService.findById(id).map( businessCustomers -> businessCustomersMapper.toFullDTO(businessCustomers));
```

source: https://github.com/rcbandit111/Search_specification_POC/blob/316c97aa5dc34488771ee11fb0dcf6dc1e4303da/src/main/java/org/merchant/service/businesscustomers/BusinessCustomersRestServiceImpl.java#L77

But I get `fullValue`. Do you know for single row how I can map the `shortValue`?

Comment: Are you saying you're trying to _write_ the value as `fullName` but _read_ it as `shortName`?

Comment: Are you saying status of  businessCustomersFullDTO.getStatus() doesn't have shortValue?

Comment: I want to write the value as a `A`  into database but in some cases display it as `shortName` and `fullName`.

Comment: @Carmel yes. I get value for `fullName`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo can use this :

```
public enum decizion{
         YES("Y"), NO("N"), OTHER;
          
         String key;
      
         decizion(String key) { this.key = key; }
     
         //default constructor, used only for the OTHER case, 
         //because OTHER doesn't need a key to be associated with. 
         decizion() { }

         static decizion getValue(String x) {
             if ("Y".equals(x)) { return YES; }
             else if ("N".equals(x)) { return NO; }
             else if (x == null) { return OTHER; }
             else throw new IllegalArgumentException();
         }
    }
```

Then, in the method, you can just do:

```
public static decizion yourDecizion() {
    ...
   String key = ...
   return decizion.getValue(key);
}
```

Comment: Can show me example with my code please?